# How can I create a new column by taking a value from an existing column and adding a specific value to that based on conditions from a diff column?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, lapply

How can I create a new column by adding a value from an existing column based on conditions from a different column? Not sure how to clearly explain this so here is an example...

Here is an example of my data:

```
structure(list(id = c(1002L, 650L, 644L, 608L, 718L, 623L, 721L, 
715L, 820L, 616L, 1001L, 634L, 1005L, 821L, 816L, 1021L, 606L, 
824L, 626L, 815L), depth = c(10L, 15L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 
20L, 5L, 20L, 5L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 20L, 10L, 20L, 5L, 20L, 20L), 
    duration = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 
    10L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 10L), catch = c(183L, 
    1216L, 159L, 232L, 1260L, 35L, 149L, 1047L, 907L, 1123L, 
    75L, 800L, 517L, 7L, 958L, 178L, 1127L, 16512L, 504L, 7890L
    ), CPH = c(1098L, 7296L, 954L, 1392L, 7560L, 210L, 894L, 
    6282L, 10884L, 6738L, 900L, 4800L, 3102L, 42L, 5748L, 1068L, 
    6762L, 198144L, 3024L, 47340L), distance = c(771.6666667, 
    771.6666667, 771.6666667, 771.6666667, 771.6666667, 771.6666667, 
    771.6666667, 771.6666667, 385.8333333, 771.6666667, 385.8333333, 
    771.6666667, 771.6666667, 771.6666667, 771.6666667, 771.6666667, 
    771.6666667, 385.8333333, 771.6666667, 771.6666667)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

I need to create a new column 'totaldist' based on the following conditions from other existing columns:

IF depth == 5, then the new 'totaldist' column should be created using = distance+111

IF depth == 10, then 'totaldist' = distance+130

IF depth == 15, then 'totaldist' = distance+185

IF depth == 20, then 'totaldist' = distance+259

For example, for ID 606 with depth 20 and distance 771.6667, the new column ('totaldist') should show a value of 1030.667 (distance+259).

I am not sure if I should use if_else, or if combined with else if, but the examples I have found using these functions have not worked for me.
Should I be trying this with lapply? Not sure how to go about this. I hope this is clear. Thank you!

Comment: Without any packages, you could use a nested ifelse().  I'm not sure if this applies, but if depths are continuous or MAY have values between your 5, 10, etc, consider making your statement able to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have multiple criteria, `case_when` may be better than `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(totaldist = case_when(depth == 5 ~ distance + 111,
                                    depth == 10 ~ distance + 130,
                                    depth == 15 ~ distance + 185,
                                    depth == 20 ~ distance + 259,
                                    TRUE ~ NA_real_))

     id depth duration catch    CPH distance totaldist
1  1002    10       10   183   1098 771.6667  901.6667
2   650    15       10  1216   7296 771.6667  956.6667
3   644    10       10   159    954 771.6667  901.6667
4   608    15       10   232   1392 771.6667  956.6667
5   718    15       10  1260   7560 771.6667  956.6667
6   623    10       10    35    210 771.6667  901.6667
7   721    10       10   149    894 771.6667  901.6667
8   715    20       10  1047   6282 771.6667 1030.6667
9   820     5        5   907  10884 385.8333  496.8333
10  616    20       10  1123   6738 771.6667 1030.6667
11 1001     5        5    75    900 385.8333  496.8333
12  634    20       10   800   4800 771.6667 1030.6667
13 1005    20       10   517   3102 771.6667 1030.6667
14  821    10       10     7     42 771.6667  901.6667
15  816    20       10   958   5748 771.6667 1030.6667
16 1021    10       10   178   1068 771.6667  901.6667
17  606    20       10  1127   6762 771.6667 1030.6667
18  824     5        5 16512 198144 385.8333  496.8333
19  626    20       10   504   3024 771.6667 1030.6667
20  815    20       10  7890  47340 771.6667 1030.6667
```

Comment: ahh! why didnt I think about case_when, I didn't know I could use that to add things like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to join with a lookup table:

```
library(dplyr)

lookup <- data.frame(
  depth = c(5, 10, 15, 20),
  added_dist = c(111, 130, 185, 259)
)

my_df %>% 
  left_join(lookup, 'depth') %>% 
  mutate(totaldist = distance + added_dist)
```

This separates the logic from the coded values, which can be nice.